# Target class [App\\Http\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful] does not exist

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, laravel-7

I am using Laravel Sanctum to authenticate a react SPA with a laravel API backend.

While I am trying to access routes which does not need authentication, I am getting this error:

"Target class [App\Http\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful] does not exist."

What should I do to guard only some routes, while leaving others open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably missing the import in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

```
// app/Http/Kernel.php

<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;
```

Comment: Ohh, that was it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can usually be solved with: `composer dump-autoload`

You can read more about what the command does [here](https://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/)

> composer dump-autoload won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.